# NHibernate Db Calls made in a web session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate

I have recently started working on a project using NHibernate as a ORM tool.I read about the contextual session in nHibernate and understood the idea behind it. I have a doubt in one area,

Let's say, i have a employee domain and in a http call,i am calling my repository for getting employee id =1 , 3 times.

Employee employee = _employeeRepository.GetEmployee(1);

Case 1: It will be a 1 db call
Case 2: It will be 3 db calls.

please guide me on this.

rgds
Sandy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your setup.

The first level cache will hit the DB once against each `Session` object you use to query with. If there is a single `Session` shared with this repository.. only one DB call will be made. However, if each call to the repository causes more than one `Session` to be created, you'll get multiple calls. This is the default.

If the second level cache is enabled, then each `Session` created via a `SessionFactory` will share the above properties. Meaning, if you have multiple repositories with multiple `Session`'s that came from the same `SessionFactory` instance.. then loading the same employee from both repositories will cause a single DB call.

[There is some good information in this post](http://www.javabeat.net/introduction-to-hibernate-caching/) - it is related to Hibernate, but the basic principles still apply to NHibernate.

I would recommend you enable a second level cache (we use SysCache2) in a web environment.. so that you can guarantee that the `Session`'s always share cached objects within a single request (assuming of course, that your `Session` lifetime management is per-request.. which is should be..).

Comment: Thanks Simon's for your explantion